# How to edit date value with date type format in bootstrap

Tags: date, asp.net-mvc-4, html.textboxfor

I have these codes but then the value display in the edit box is "mm/dd/yyyy"
[image]

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @Value = Model.StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), @placeholder= Model.StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), @class = "form-control", @type="date" })
```

How can I achieve something like this where the displayed date is the value from the database and not "mm/dd/yyyy"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, don't set the `value` attribute directly. Razor will pretty much ignore this anyways. The value for a bound field comes from `ModelState`, which is itself composed of values from `Request`, `ViewBag/ViewData`, and `Model`, in that order. So, for example, if you want `StartDate` to default to "today", then you would simply populate your model with that in the action before you return the view:

```
model.StartDate = DateTime.Today;
```

Or, better, you can change the property on your model class to default to today automatically:

```
private DateTime? startDate;
public DateTime StartDate
{
    get { return startDate ?? DateTime.Today; }
    set { startDate = value; }
}
```

Just bear in mind that if your action happens to take a param like `startDate` or you set something like `ViewBag.StartDate`, those values will always take precedence.

Second, you're utilizing an HTML5 `date` input type. In browsers that support the HTML5 input types, the supplied value for a datetime, date or time, *must* be in ISO format. For a date, that means `YYYY-MM-DD`. If the value is not supplied like that, then the browser considers it garbage and discards it, leaving the control as if no value was supplied.

Also, FWIW, you don't need to prefix every member of your anonymous object with `@`. It doesn't technically hurt anything, but it's code smell. The `@` prefix exists to escape language keywords. With `class`, for example, you can't use it directly since it's a keyword, so you have to use `@class` instead. However, things like `placeholder` and `type` are *not* keywords, and therefore don't need an `@` prefix.

Comment: StartDate have always a data which is a date type. How would I achieve in displaying the date value and not "mm/dd/yyyy; ?